# Attempt to delete prototype of HTMLElement fails

Tags: javascript

I was trying to delete `.insertBefore();` of `HTMLElement.prototype` but when I check for it, instead of an undefined value, it returns the actual function? Why?

```
console.log(HTMLElement.prototype.insertBefore); // function insertBefore() { [native code] }

delete HTMLElement.prototype.insertBefore;

console.log(HTMLElement.prototype.insertBefore); // function insertBefore() { [native code] }
```

Can you explain why this isn't working. I tried this on my own constructor and it worked, but for the built in ones, it didn't.

Comment: Which browsers have you tested? You may find you get different results.

Comment: How come you would want to do that? Intellectually curious here.

Comment: I'm trying to write my own framework. Just for fun, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use DELETE like that:

http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

> **Property attributes**
>
> Every property can have zero or more attributes from the following set — ReadOnly, DontEnum, DontDelete and Internal. You can think of them as flags — an attribute can either exist on a property or not. For the purposes of today’s discussion, we are only interested in DontDelete.
>
> **Built-ins and DontDelete**
>
> So this is what it’s all about: a special attribute on a property that controls whether this property can be deleted or not. Note that some of the properties of built-in objects are specified to have DontDelete, and so can not be deleted. Special arguments variable (or, as we know now, a property of Activation object) has DontDelete. length property of any function instance has DontDelete as well.

Seriously man, read that article. It has a ludicrously clear and concise explanation of all this!

---

**Note:** even though they have the `dontDelete` attribute set, you can still overwrite it:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.insertBefore = '';
// or
HTMLElement.prototype.insertBefore = null;
// or
HTMLElement.prototype.insertBefore = undefined;
```

Comment: Before I read the article, can I just say that I thought that you could delete object properties just like that using the `delete` keyword? And isn't `.prototype` and object?

Comment: @David - You are absolutely right: You *can* delete object properties just like that using the `delete` keyword. However, most of the native functions/methods have the `dontDelete` attribute set: http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#property_attributes

Answer (score 1):

The browser implementation(s) probably have that property set as non-configurable.

There may be a greater chance that it is writable though:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.insertBefore = null;

console.log(HTMLElement.prototype.insertBefore); // null
```

Keep in mind that objects like `HTMLElement` are host objects, and therefore don't necessarily follow all the same rules of regular JavaScript objects.

For example, trying to `delete` a non-configurable property when in *strict mode* should throw an error, but testing this in Chrome, no error is thrown.

http://jsfiddle.net/YrvE4/2/

---

Seen here, you if you create your own custom property, you can `delete` that just fine:

```
"use strict";

HTMLElement.prototype.custom_property = 'value';  // new property

console.log(HTMLElement.prototype.custom_property);  // value

try {
    delete HTMLElement.prototype.custom_property;
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}

console.log(HTMLElement.prototype.custom_property);  // undefined
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YrvE4/3/

Answer (score 0):

`HTMLElement.prototype`, like all of DOM, is a "host object", which is basically something provided by the ECMAScript environment that isn't defined in the ECMAScript spec. Host objects have few rules they have to follow: it is perfectly allowable for `[[Delete]]` to do nothing, even if `Object.getPropertyDescriptor` has `[[Configurable]]: false`.